# How to handle the table results returned by a function in function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres function that calls another function which returns a table.

What I can't find an example of is how and what to assign the returned table to in the first function so it can be used?

I plan to foreach over the returned table data in the first function calling further functions based upon the data.

Comment: `select * from some_function(42)` will need to be treated the same as a "normal" query like `select * from some_table`. But without more details this is nearly impossible to answer)

Answer (score 0):

That's rather embarrassing, think I just found the answer...

```
declare item record;
.
.
.
for item in select * from second_fuction()
loop
    doSomething(item.field);
end loop;
```